# Передача по ссылке объекта в функцию

Tags: c++

Когда я передаю некий объект  переменную в функцию по ссылке в C++, то содержимое ссылки при этом полностью копируется в стек либо же в стек кидается только указатель на переменную, а обращение происходит также как к переменной  объекту по указателю только без применения оператора разыменования?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По части расходования памяти ссылка в C++ занимает столько же места, сколько и указатель, и копирования объекта не возникает (а используется его адрес). Так что по части расходования памяти они эквивалентны.

Answer (score 0):

Ссылку можно определить как константный разыменованный указатель (не путать с указателем на константу). Потому скорее второй вариант.